# A different way of handling this promise?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, promise, when-js

Here's a little bit of CoffeeScript, but feel free to answer in JavaScript:

```
model = new MyModel content: content
model.save()
@collection.add model
```

Elsewhere, a view is listening for the `add` event on the collection:

```
_addOne: (model, collection, options)=>
  view = new MyView model: model
  @subviews[model.id] = view
```

Sometimes the model hadn't finished talking to the server, so it didn't have an `id` and this code failed to do what was wanted. So, I wrapped the `save` in a promise using the when.js library (`when` is mapped to `When` here)

```
When model.save()
  .then =>
    @collection.add model
```

Now all is hunky dory with the world. What I'm wondering is, is there a way to get the `then` into the `_addOne` method, because that's the bit that's *really* waiting, the collection itself doesn't mind getting a half-baked model added to it.

How can I proceed?

Comment: @SLaks I wouldn't know how to do that - can I wrap attributes in `When`? I'm still getting my head around the whole promise thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Collection#create`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) instead:

> **createcollection.create(attributes, [options])**
>
> Convenience to create a new instance of a model within a collection. Equivalent to instantiating a model with a hash of attributes, saving the model to the server, and adding the model to the set after being successfully created. [...] Pass `{wait: true}` if you'd like to wait for the server before adding the new model to the collection.

So if you do this:

```
@collection.create(
  { content: content }
  { wait: true }
)
```

Then the model won't be added to the collection until the server has responded and the model will have its server-supplied `id` by then.

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly a better way to do things.